# Getting JEditorPane to work

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

Okay, so here's my problem. I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SongTapper extends JFrame {

    Date d;
    boolean isFirstTap = true;
    static JTapper tap;
    URL url;

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    JScrollPane scroll;
    JFrame frame;

    public void show() {
//      d = new Date();
//      Date d2 = new Date();
//      
//      double seconds = ((d.getTime() - d2.getTime()) /1000);
//      
//      System.out.println(seconds);

        frame = new JFrame();
        tap = new JTapper();
        tap.setEditable(false);
        tap.setText("Tap out a song using the Space bar");

        tap.addTapListener(new TapListener() {

            String count = "";

            @Override
            public void tapPerformed() {

                if(isFirstTap){
                    d = new Date();
                    isFirstTap = false;
                }else{
                    Date tapping = new Date();

                    double seconds = (((double)tapping.getTime() - (double)d.getTime()) / 1000.0);

                    String total = Double.toString(seconds) + "-0-1/";

                    System.out.println(count += total);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void tappingCompleted() {
                tap.setText("Tapping completed");
                String fullUrl = "http://www.musipedia.org/result.html?sourceid=melody-url&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bsubmit_button%5d=Search&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bpc%5d=hum%20" + 
                        count +"&filtertext=&coll=r&onlymatchfrom=0 ";
                try {
                    url = new URL(fullUrl);
                    pane.setPage(url);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                frame = new JFrame();
                 scroll = new JScrollPane(pane);
                frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
                frame.pack();

            }

        });

        frame.setTitle("Song Tapper");

        //frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(tap);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTapper extends JTextField implements KeyListener {

JLabel label = new JLabel("Tap out a song using the Space bar");
int count;
List<TapListener> taps = new ArrayList<TapListener>();

public JTapper(){

    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

public void addTapListener(TapListener tapListener){
    taps.add(tapListener);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 32){
        for(TapListener tap : taps){
            tap.tapPerformed();
        }
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == 10){
        for(TapListener tap : taps){
            tap.tappingCompleted();
        }
    }
}

}
```

and what I'm trying to do is replace the middle part of a url with the timing of a space bar tap, but I'm having trouble getting it to pull up the JEditorPane with the desired website inside of it.

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix it so that it displays the webpage I'm requesting?

If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Comment: To start with, don't use `KeyListener` with text components, consider using `DocumentListener`

Answer (score 1):

The Url part would be nice and easy-ish:

```
String part = JTapper.getTapNumber()+"";//if it exists
//if it doesn't exist just make it
${name_of_JEditorPane}.setPage(new URL("http://www.example.com/"+part+"ending"));
```

To pull up the JEditorPane you would make a JFrame with the pane inside it but I have to warn you! You should not use JEditorPAnes to show Webpages, as they can only use basic html and cannot run javascript!